# Tautology symbol Agda

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, agda

What is the keyboard shortcut for the tautology and contradiction symbols (T and upside down T) in Agda? This extensive list of shortcuts doesn't seem to show how to make them: 
http://people.inf.elte.hu/divip/AgdaTutorial/Symbols.html#1
I have tried \T and others, but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried `\top` and `\bot`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortcut symbols are \top and \bot.

Comment: Oops sorry. I wrote the answer but I didn't see Vitus' comment.

Comment: That's okay, I wasn't writing an answer anyways. :)